# Windows 10 / MSI laptop / HGST HTS drive not available

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, drivers

**File Explorer**

[[image: File Explorer shows only C:\ and D:][1]]

Just installed Win 10 on my "old" MSI laptop.  Easily installed on the main SSD drive.  At the time of installation, both drives were visible.  However, upon installation, the second drive (1 TB) is not showing up under File Explorer.

**Device Manager**
[image: Device Manager shows HGST is functioning properly]

The Device Manager shows the drive exists, it is operating properly and I cannot update the driver "automatically" because it claims that it has the latest driver (really?  from 2006?).

**Driver snapshots**

[image: HGST driver]

[image: Samsung driver]

**Disk Management**
[image: Disk Management]

Brand of the drive that is not cooperating is not obvious.  It just says *HGST HTS721010A9E630*.  I assume this is the Hitachi product that Western Digital purchased, but I'm really not sure.

Suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Disk Management, showing all your storage devices, this information is required to answer your question.

Comment: Try to open Device Manager, right-click the hard drive, choose Uninstall, confirm deletion of the Driver files, and restart the PC so Windows can install a new driver.

Comment: Thanks for the interest!  I added screenshots that I hope will help to explain the situation.

Comment: I've already tried to uninstall the device.  I'm afraid to delete the driver files.  If I do that, won't I disable both the Samsung SSD (boot driver) as well as the HGST.

Comment: Don’t delete or uninstall drivers.  It won’t solve your problem.  Just assign a drive letter to the partition using Disk Management

Comment: @user3533030, how did you install Windows 10? Did you manually update using a USB key? Also, at the time that you upgraded to the next version of Windows, did you have internet connectivity? Finally, what version of Windows did you update from?

Comment: Also, can you file a feedback using the feedback hub app, and then paste a link to the feedback in the comments here? Use category "Files Folders and Online Storage" and subcategory "Disks and Storage" https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021566/windows-10-send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-feedback-hub

Comment: I performed a new install from a USB drive.  I wiped the existing Win 7 O/S.  I'm not sure how to provide the feedback you're requesting.  What is the *feedback hub app*?

Answer (score -1):

I think https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound provided the critical clues for an answer.

Using Disk Management, I discovered that the drive did not have an assigned drive letter.  Assigning E:\ seems to have made it operational.  I'll reboot and double check.

Thanks!